# How to left align default bootstrap 5 accordion icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get something like this:

[image: desired result]

And this is the current result:

[image: current result]

What I've tried:

```
.accordion-button::after {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
}
```

Unfortunately `float: left;` did not worked.

Any ideas?

Here is a [LIVE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/40/)

**UPDATE:**

If I get rid of `margin-left: auto` as Sato Takeru suggested, the icon gets closer to the text, but it will still be aligned to the right.

[image: updated]

Comment: Remove `margin-left: auto`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Satoさん、yeah I also tried that before, what it will do is move the icon closer to the text, but it will still be aligned to the right.

Comment: Question updated with @SatoTakeru comment

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the flex `order` property

```
.accordion-button:after {
    order: -1; //swap order
    margin-left: 0; 
    margin-right:0.5em; // just extra space between text and icon
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know `order: -1` before. Thank you @herrstrietzel.

Comment: Actually changing it to `a:before` pseuo element would be the more appropriate method as @MeltingDog recommended. Changing the order would rather be a 'quick and dirty'  solution to keep your existing css.

Answer (score 4):

There is no default support for this in bootstrap. I've solved it by custom class in .accordion .right for aligning it. ([working example](https://4bis.nl/nl/page/diensten))

**End result:**
[image]

My code in **scss** is using a custom icons for opening and closing:

```
.accordion {
  &.right {
    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::before {
      background-image: url("../images/x.svg");
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }

    .accordion-button::before {
      height: 1.5rem;
      background-image: url('../images/plus.svg');

      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: $accordion-icon-width;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: $accordion-icon-width;
      content: "";
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: $accordion-icon-width;
      @include transition($accordion-icon-transition);
    }
    .accordion-button::after {
      display: none;
    }

    .accordion-collapse {
      margin-left: 2*$accordion-icon-width;
    }
  }
}
```

My compiled code in **css** is using a custom icons for opening and closing:

```
.accordion.right .accordion-button:not(.collapsed):before {
    background-image: url(/build/images/x.svg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.accordion.right .accordion-button:before {
    background-image: url(/build/images/plus.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    content: "";
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1.25rem;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 1.25rem;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .accordion.right .accordion-button:before {
        transition: none;
    }
}
.accordion.right .accordion-button:after {
    display: none;
}
.accordion.right .accordion-collapse {
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom class to change the pseudo to `::before` and remove the `margin-left`.

**Note:**

You have to hide `::after` pseudo element.

Eg:

```
.myaccordion .accordion-button::before {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion-button::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: If so, there are two arrows. `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to either modify the bootstrap css (not advisable) or hide the after.

Comment: Yes, so you should write that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5.3 + Webpack:

```
.accordion {
  &.reversed {
    .accordion-button {
      @extend .accordion-button;

      &:before {
        @extend ::after;
        display: block !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        margin-right: 0.5rem !important; // extra space between text and icon
      }

      &:after {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Than add class '.reversed' to the top element of accordion:

```
<div class="accordion reversed" id="accordionExample">
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hx223u?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Do you have a jsfiddle by chance?