# How can I move this Bootstrap 5 accordion's arrows so they are before the text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So this is the example from Bootstrap 5 web page. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/)
My question is, how can I possibly make the arrows be before the text. I tried different things but I couldn't get it to work.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One of the things I tried using the inspector is to switch `margin-right: auto;` to `margin-left: auto;` and I was able to align it left but its still right after the text. Here is the CSS I modified

```
    .accordion-button::after {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show what errors you hit? Do not ask for a ready solution, s you will not learn anything from that

Comment: Ok my apologies, I added a little more details about what have I tried. So far I used the inspector and change the margin-right  to left but and it put the arrow next to the text.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833687/how-to-left-align-default-bootstrap-5-accordion-icon) has a few answers. I just tried this CSS and it worked:

```css
.accordion-button::before {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    content: "";
    background-image: var(--bs-accordion-btn-active-icon);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.25rem;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
    
.accordion-button::after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Essentially what we are doing is:

1. Making a new ::before element and styling it the same as the bootstrap default
2. Hiding the built in bootstrap ::after element. I suppose you could also use something like jquery to remove it